# What is the best way to teach mathematical analysis via YouTube videos?

Tags: proof-explanation, education

I recently took a mathematical analysis course with covered topics such as convergence, continuity, derivatives, integrals, convergence of sequences and series, pointwise convergence of sequences of functions.

I contacted the author and publisher of the textbook that was used for this course and asked for their permission if I could make YouTube video tutorials using content from their book.  Both parties are interested in seeing what I do and have given me temporary permission to upload a handful of videos (privately) so they can look through and approve them for becoming public videos.

My question to the math teaching community is: What is the best approach to teaching proof-heavy material on YouTube?

I am initially inclined to follow exactly what [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) does.  But most of the videos on this website are not exactly proof-heavy.  The material I want to attack can be abstract.  Should I follow what KA does in their YouTube videos or is there a better way to enhance these videos for understanding abstract math analysis?

Comment: Check out Francis Su's lectures on Real Analysis.  They are great.

Comment: you must work a lot of examples, more than in textbooks, from the simpler ones to some more harder. Anyway examples probably are not enough to capture the generality of theorems.

Comment: This question is probably better asked on https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I wished people would ask about videos at youtube, and about mathematics here.

Comment: Certainly no need to reproduce the textbook proof on a blackboard. Like so many lecturers do. It's not suitable for a video course. Rather, you need to discuss the implications, the place of the theorem in the more general context. Possibly the historical context, how it was first proposed, how long did it take to prove it, etc. In any case, do not try to reproduce textbook proofs verbatim, that's my advice